# How can I change my system Library from jre to jdk in java Maven

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors, command-prompt

[image]As You can see from this picture I have my jre using here but instead of that I want to use jdk. Any help would be great.

Comment: No picture, but the JRE is **not** a compiler.

Comment: `set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_191"` or wherever you have your JDK (and you should be using a 64-bit JDK on 64-bit Windows, for about the last decade).

Comment: It has attached now. Please check